# How can I view systemd timers for all users?

Tags: linux, sudo, systemd

I have some users running in linger mode on Ubuntu and Arch Linux systemd systems. Meaning, users' timers can be running even if they are not logged into the system. As a root user, how can I see all the timers active, including all of the users' timers?

`systemctl list-timers` will give me the system timers.
If I am logged in as a user `systemctl --user list-timers` will give me the timers for that user. However, if I run `sudo -u anotheruser systemctl --user list-timers` then I get `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the Freenode #systemd IRC channel (users dreisner and damjan),
I learned that systemd requires the user to run `systemctl --user list-timers` in order to print the running timers.

If an administrator of the system wants to `sudo` or `su` as another user in order to see the timers, then they need to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` envrionment variable.

For example `sudo -u $anotheruser XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$anotheruser_uid systemctl --user list-timers` will return `$anotheruser` timers.

To automate the process of viewing all timers on the system, I created a script in [Bash](https://github.com/dmp1ce/list-all-systemd-timers/blob/master/list-all-systemd-timers.bash) and [Haskell](https://github.com/dmp1ce/list-all-systemd-timers/blob/master/list-all-systemd-timers.hs).

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution is to do the following..

```
sudo systemctl --machine=<username>@.host --user list-timers
```

Replace `<username>` with the appropriate, and `systemctl` should populate the required environment.